# What is the rule of precedence when providing services through multiple directives?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-di

I'd like to be able to modify component-behaviour by adding directives.

```
<demo>Basic behaviour</demo>
<demo dira>Modified behaviour</demo>
```

My approach is to define the behaviour in service-classes, that are provided by and to the component. The directives have their own service-provider and thus override the provider of the component.

```
@Component({
    selector: "demo",
    providers: [SampleService]
})
export class DemoComponent{
    constructor( private sampleService: SampleService) {
    }
}

@Directive({
    selector: "[dira]",
    providers: [ {provide:SampleService, useClass:SpecialSampleService}]
})
export class DirADirective {
}
```

This does work, but I can't find a rule about what happens, when there are multiple directives providing a service with the same token:

```
<demo dira dirb></demo>
```

From my observation, it seems that a provider from a directive always takes precedence over a provider from a component. Between the directives it is always the last one in the declarations-array (not in the HTML) that "wins".

Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/jdN9GaRTzoe7UQj2PIeP?p=preview

My question is if this kind of provider-overriding is supported and if I can at least rely on my assumption, that services provided by directives always take precedence over services provided by components?

Answer (score 0):

Component `DemoComponent` and it's children will get a `SampleService` injected when they have a `SampleService` constructor parameters.

Directive `DirADirective` will get a `SpecialSampleService` injected.

DI looks at the component or directive that has a constructor parameter for providers. If it can't find a matching provider it keeps looking on the parents until it finds one.

The last resort is the root scope, where providers added to `@NgModule()` are kept.

So the rule of precedence is, self, parent, parent of parent, ... root scope.

Comment: What is the relation of directives to components regarding the component-tree? Are they considered children, parents or some kind of siblings? From my testing, DemoComponent gets injected the SpecialSampleService from its DirADirective, even though it provides its own SampleService. So either I haven't understood the resulting component-hierarchy or the rules by which the injector merges the providers of the component and its directives.

Comment: They are siblings. "DemoComponent gets injected the SpecialSampleService" If that is the case, that's quite surprising to me too.

Comment: Perhaps they share a scope if they are added to the same element and the providers of the directive are added later and override the providers of the component. https://plnkr.co/edit/zYQVsLdsHpsmqLsLF19O?p=preview. Very interesting case.

Comment: Looks that way. If there is no provider for the directive, only for the component, the directive still gets the provider from the component while I expected it to throw "no provider found". https://plnkr.co/edit/nYDI2Ctqtf6C0DOIjbnV?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for investigating. I couldn't find any documentation on this but the behaviour seems intentional to me. Otherwise, what would be the point for a directive to provide a service if it couldn't be shared?

Comment: I agree, it makes sense to me as well. I'm still wondering why I never saw thus situation mentoned before.